# PHP - Generate random numbers with no duplicates

Tags: php

I'm building an advent calendar in PHP 7 and want to show dates 1 - 24 in a random order.

I've got a jquery plugin which can randomise my `div` elements, but it's not very good, and I want to know how to do it in PHP.

My code to output the dates looks (in simplified terms) like this:

```
for ($d = 1; $d <= 24; $d++) {
    echo $d;
}
```

My plan was to instead use `rand(1, 24)` then store any numbers that had been generated in an array, e.g.

```
$date = rand(1, 24);
$used_dates[] = $date;
```

Then check `$used_dates` when picking a new date, e.g.

```
$unique_date = false;
while (!$unique_date) {
    $date = rand(1, 24);
    if (!in_array($date, $used_dates)) {
       $used_dates[] = $date;
       $unique_date = true;
    }
}
```

This seems inefficient though. Are there better ways?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your case, you need create range array of numbers, and then simply shuffle them

```
$days = range(1,24);
shuffle($days);
```

Thats all

Answer (score 3):

You can use shuffle() method.

Shuffle() take an array and order rows randomly.

```
$array = array("a", "b", "c");
shuffle($array);
// OUTPUT is random
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$numbers = range(1, 24);
shuffle($numbers);
```