# How can I get multiple individual rotating random images from a designated folder

Tags: php, image, slideshow

I am currently using this random image gen to populate individual Div's on the page. How can I make it so each div has its own random rotating image. Here is the code I have so far.

```
$imagesDir = 'images/test/';
$images = glob($imagesDir . '*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE);
$randomImage = $images[array_rand($images)];
    echo'
    <div id="baloon1">
        <img src="' . $randomImage  . '">
    </div>';
    $randomImage = $images[array_rand($images)];
    echo'
    <div id="baloon2">
        <img src="' . $randomImage  . '">
    </div>';
    $randomImage = $images[array_rand($images)];
    echo'
    <div id="baloon3">
        <img src="' . $randomImage  . '">
    </div>';
    $randomImage = $images[array_rand($images)];
    echo'
    <div id="baloon4">
        <img src="rotate.php">
    </div>';
```

Comment: You mean to change the images folder (for selecting random image) for each div? If so you need to repeat the first two lines before each echo to update your image folder.

Comment: not to change the folder. to have a random from the folder fade in then out then when clicked switch to a new random image from the same folder then fade in fade out

Answer (score 0):

try this way (inspired by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40805302/php-generate-random-numbers-with-no-duplicates)):

```
    $imagesDir = 'images/test/';
    $images = glob($imagesDir . '*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE);
    $imageList = range(0,count($images));
    shuffle($imageList);
    $image_idx = 0;
    echo'
    <div id="baloon1">
        <img src="' . $images[$imageList[$image_idx++]]. '">
    </div>';
    echo'
    <div id="baloon2">
        <img src="' . $images[$imageList[$image_idx++]]. '">
    </div>';

    echo'
    <div id="baloon3">
        <img src="' . $images[$imageList[$image_idx++]]. '">
    </div>';

    echo'
    <div id="baloon4">
        <img src="' . $images[$imageList[$image_idx++]]. '">
    </div>';
```

Comment: well that does make them each individually random. sometimes it call no image and leaves one blank also it is not rotating through the images for each div but that part might be another step entirely

Comment: You asked to have a random rotating image for each div, and this is what this code does, without duplicates images in each div. If you to rotate the image with fade in and fade out, you should use javascript. You cannot do that with PHP

Comment: understandable and thank you. why is it still calling a blank image when loaded sometimes though ? it doesnt matter if some of the divs are the same image though as long as the populate with random to begin with. I do however have JS in place fading the current images just havnt added a on click or something yet

Comment: @Flexxall, when it calls a blank image maybe it's a problem with the JS?

Comment: I think i need to add a if statement to filter !empty